# How to convert editable python file to executable?

Tags: python, tkinter, executable

I've been working on a program to help me with organization with my classes using Tkinter. The main issue I've run into has been finding a way to make it into an executable so that I don't constantly need to run the program from the command line.

Another problem i was running into when choosing a way was, since the program uses links to operate I wanted to have a way to edit those links. Should something like that be baked into the original program or can it be separated into a txt or ini file?

Comment: People typically use [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) for this.

Comment: When I try using pyinstaller it pulls up the terminal for a second then closes it without opening the Tkinter window

Comment: What is the command you are passing to pyinstaller? Pyinstaller is just a build tool - it won't open the tkinter window, it's building an executable for your application.